# Android using LocationManager Get Provider is "Passive" in My Moto G Android Phone

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

I need a little help with some information about LocationManager in Android. I'm using this code to get user's specific information depending on his location,but in My Device Motorola G  **I get provider="Passive"** and also **Location return Null** My Motorola G is running on **Latest Android Kit Kat(4.4) Android Os**.

I also try this code in Other Devices so Provider is either Network Or GPS also find Location properly.

```
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSherlockActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW); 
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "Location not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is somehow an old question. But hope my answer will help others as well.

The issue is not related to the used device, actually the issue is how we use  the provided API.

In the following code snippet, you pass true for the enabledOnly flag while you just need to pass it as false and it will work correctly at this time.

Instead of :
`provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);`

To be:
`provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);`

To clear this point:

- If we set this flag "enabledOnly flag" to true, this means to return the requested best provider based on our criteria from the enabled only providers which will return the Passive provider.
- While, if we set it to false, this will mean to return the requested best provider based on our criteria even if it is not enabled, which will return gps.

Btw, I am using Moto G too -but it's 2nd Gen- , and it worked with me this way :)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

READ THIS IF YOUR APP SUPPORTS kITKAT(4.4) VERSION OF ANDROID 
I was having the same issue and my code was working perfectly in other devices not running kitkat,after a little bit of snooping around i found out that  you have to explicitly turn on GPS to get location through wifi/gps. you can read about it here.
https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3467281

Comment: I don't see the relevance; sorry